# Akka cluster nodes with actors leave

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

Lets say that I have 4 nodes (N1, N2, N3, N4) in an Akka cluster. Suppose I have actor with name **A** deployed N4 (by the akka system and transparent to the user). If I decided that I no longer need a lot of computing power, I would *scale down* the servers to only have 2 nodes, thus node N3 and node N4 are powered down. What would happen to actor **A**? Would it be dead and should be recreated manually by application logic? Would it be automatically recreated on another node (even with the state lost)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a regular actor on a node and you shut down that node the actor will be shut down together with the actor system. There are some tools that you can use if you want a specific actor to (almost) always be alive on some node, `ClusterSingleton` keeps an actor alive on one node as continuously as possible without ever having multiple instances of it in the cluster, `ClusterSharding` makes it possible to keep actors alive and redistributable across cluster using an identifier. Akka persistence allows for the state of an actor survive being stopped on one node and started on another.

Read more about all of this in the docs, and I really recommend reading the general sections on what akka cluster is to get a firm understanding before starting to use it: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/index-network.html

Comment: Thanks @johanandren! There are so much about Akka that I have to learn.